# Passing Data to Previous ViewController by dismissing Present ViewController

Tags: ios, swift4

I have 2 `ViewControllers`

1. `ViewControllerA`,
2. `ViewControllerB`

`ViewControllerB` is to show `popUpView` and another is my `mainViewController`.
When I press cancel button in `popUpView` I dismiss the present `ViewController` (i.e `ViewControllerB`) and try to pass some data to `ViewControllerA`.
I tried to print value in `viewWillAppear()` function of `ViewControllerA` but after dismiss I am not receiving any data from `ViewControllerB`.

Can anyone help me out how to solve this?

Comment: Please add the code you have tried to pass the data.

Comment: You can use block method, delegate, NotificationCenter to pass data from ViewController B to ViewController A.

Comment: @IBAction func cancelAction(_ sender: Any) {
        
        if let presenter = presentingViewController as? MGM_Selection{
            presenter.flag = 1
            presenter.viewWillAppear(true)
        }
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        
    }

Comment: ok i will try with delegate

Comment: delegate solved my problem thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Comment: An unwind (exit) segue is also a mechanism designed for this scenario.